# Can't get data from Firebase Database on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a set up where I want to get data from the Database on Firebase, I can get the URL back fine but I can't get data from it. When I try to debug it reads in `query.addValueEventListener` but after that it just goes straight to my list adapter. I don't know it's not getting the data. I have a similar set up on my node server which works perfectly fine, but won't work on Android for some reason

```
 final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = database.child("exercises");
Log.i("Database query", database.child("exercises").toString());
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot exerciseSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            List<ExerciseList> exercises = new ArrayList<ExerciseList>();
            ExerciseList exerciseList = exerciseSnapshot.getValue(ExerciseList.class);
            Log.i("description/name", exerciseList.getDescription() + " " + exerciseList.getName());
            exercises.add(exerciseList);
            adapter = new ExerciseLoadListAdapter(mActivity, exercises);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: database]

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its go to `adapter` directly because `addValueEventListener()` is `Asynchronous listeners` , its run in background !

Try this code , it may be help you !

```
final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Query query = database.child("exercises");
    //Log.i("Database query", database.child("exercises").toString());
    database.child("exercises").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot exerciseSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                List<ExerciseList> exercises = new ArrayList<ExerciseList>();
                ExerciseList exerciseList = exerciseSnapshot.getValue(ExerciseList.class);
                Log.i("description/name", exerciseList.getDescription() + " " + exerciseList.getName());
                exercises.add(exerciseList);

            }
               adapter = new ExerciseLoadListAdapter(mActivity, exercises);
               mListView.setAdapter(adapter)
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Still didn't work, would the fact I'm working inside a fragment affect this at all?

Comment: are you sure, you are getting data from `firebase`? `fragment` is not causing any problem

Comment: When I get the log for the `database.child("exercises").toString()` I get a link to the database and everything inside it.

Comment: `04-12 16:56:30.375 17461-17461/com.android.fitnessapp I/Database query: databaseurl/exercises`

Comment: i think ,you are not set the path of your `firebase database`

Comment: `04-12 16:56:30.375 17461-17461/com.android.fitnessapp I/Database query: https://final-year-project-9b6cb.firebaseio.com/exercises` this is the proper URL here

Comment: what do you get here? Log.i("description/name", exerciseList.getDescription() + " " + exerciseList.getName());

Comment: nothing because nothing happens after the ` query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`

Comment: try my updated code ! , also show your `firebase database` structuring !

Comment: i did try your code and nothing changed I'll upload a picture of the database now

Comment: your database looks fine , do one thing comment for loop and put log there and see whats value of snapshot ! , also check rules !

Comment: Nothing comes out of the snapshot, the newValueEventListener() is never called for w/e reason. So it just ignores it. I've tried the rules as == null and != null. Neither change anything

Comment: I don't get anything

Comment: try this rule  `{ "rules": { ".read": "auth == null", ".write": "auth == null" } } ` or  { "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true } }

Comment: try this  inside for loop `Log.d("value" ,""+exerciseSnapshot);` and see value !

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase do **NOT** get the data in the debug mode in real time. If you need some object from your firebase database you will need to get the object before. I face this problem a several times, thats why in some cases I use SQLite to store data from Firebase before i take any action. But, in a **fragment** you can not do that, you need the data in realtime. So you need to store the listener in a variable and use it after. Here in my Github page I have a fragment working fine.
[ContatsFragment.java](https://github.com/evandrogrm/App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/checkup/app/fragment/ContatsFragment.java)
[]'s